# Sort ArrayList by Objects containing three values

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList containng Objects which contain three values, now I'd like to sort them by these values:

```
List<AvailablePeriod> periodList = new ArrayList<AvailablePeriod>
```

And an AvailablePeriod object contains:

```
DateTime start
DateTime end
int id
```

I'd like to have the objects in the list sorted first by start, than end and last by id.

Can't get the sorting figured out..

Comment: I believe that this post can solve your problem: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Comment: My problem is the multiple value part, no need to downvote before giving a chance to explain -_-

Answer (score 0):

Write a comparator as below

```
   public class MyComparator implements Comparator<AvailablePeriod> {
    @Override
    public int compare(AvailablePeriod o1, AvailablePeriod o2) {
        int result = o1.getStart().compareTo(o2.getStart());
        if (result == 0) {
            result = o1.getEnd().compareTo(o2.getEnd());
        }
        if (result == 0) {
            result = Integer.valueOf(o1.getId()).compareTo(o2.getId());
        }
        return result;
    }
   }
```

Then use Collection.sort method

```
List<AvailablePeriod> periodList = new ArrayList<AvailablePeriod>
Collections.sort(periodList , new MyComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class xyz implements Comparable {
    DateTime start;
    DateTime end;
    int id;
```

`@Override
public int compareTo(xyz o) {
    if (this.start.isBefore(o.start)) {
        return -1;

    } else if (o.start.isBefore(o.start)) {

        return -1;

    } else {
        if (this.end.isBefore(o.end)) {
            return -1;

        } else if (o.end.isBefore(this.end)) {

            return 1;

        } else {
            if (this.id > o.id) {
                return 1;

            } else if (this.id < o.id) {

                return -1;

            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }

}

}`

You can write something like this.And then use collections.sort(list)